# How to call js function from a hbs file in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

this is the main app in ember.js

app/templates/application.hbs

```
{{page-title "User Management"}}
<ul>
  <LinkTo @route="print-user" >Print User</LinkTo>
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

This is the code to get the json-array response from servlet

app/components/print-user.js

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import {action} from "@ember/object";
import {tracked} from "@glimmer/tracking";
export default class PrintUserComponent extends Component {
    @tracked search="";
    @tracked print="";
    @tracked gotresponse=false;
    @action 
    async searchuser (searchtext){
        let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/SearchServlet",
        {   method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "type": "search",
                "searchtext": searchtext
            })
        });
        let parsed=await response.json();
        this.gotresponse=true;
        this.search=parsed;
    }
    async deleteuser (id,firstname,lastname,mailid){
        let response=await fetch("/UserManagement/UserManagementServlet",
        {   method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "type": "delete",
                "id": id,
                "firstname":firstname,
                "lastname":lastname,
                "mailid":mailid
            })
        });
        let parsed=await response.json();
        alert(parsed.status);
    }
}
```

This is the hbs code to print the user table in webpage

app/components/print-user.hbs

```
<input5>{{input type="text" value=search placeholder="Enter Text"}}</input5>
<searchbutton {{on "click" (fn this.searchuser search )}}>Search</searchbutton>

<table class="styled-table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>User Id</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Mailid</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    {{#each this.search.Users_data as |user|}}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                <td>{{user.firstname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.lastname}}</td>
                <td>{{user.mailid}}</td>
                <td><button {{on "click" (fn deleteuser user.id user.firstname user.lastname user.mailid )}}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    {{/each}}
</table>
{{yield}}
```

I need to print the user data while clicking the print user in application.hbs
It is working properly when I click search button.
I Don't know how to print the user details without clicking button....

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly doesn't work? I can see that you use the same `searchuser` action for the print button handler. How does that suppose to work?

Comment: If I click print user from the application.hbs. I have to display the search option and user details. I implemented to display the user details only after pressing the search button. But I have to display the user details while entering the page

Comment: Have you considered using the `did-insert` modifier?

Comment: Not yet. But i will try it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I want to call a function (which is present in the print-user.js) from print-user.hbs to get the response from the servlet.

Comment: Ok, so apparently you want to call the `searchuser` action *on the component* without need to click the button on the component, i.e. when the component is shown. Use the `did-insert` for that. And let me be a bit of pain in the neck here but it took quite a while to understand what needs to be done because there was too much code and the incorrect phrasing about "need to print the user data while clicking the print user in application.hbs" which led to confusion.

Comment: Sorry for making the confusion. I am new to asking question.

Comment: will you please help me on how to use did-insert modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just call the `searchuser` action manually from the `constructor`:

```
constructor() {
  super(...arguments);
  this.searchuser('default search value');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to call the `searchuser` action on the component without need to click the button on the component, i.e. when the component is shown. Use the `did-insert` modifier for that.

Usuall that goes like this: you put the modifier on a tag in a component. In your case the `<input5>` or `searchbutton` would do.

```
<input5 {{did-insert this.searchuser}}>
  {{input type="text" value=search placeholder="Enter Text"}}
</input5>

etc...
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Attempted to resolve `did-insert`, which was expected to be a modifier, but nothing was found.
    at resolveModifier (opcode-compiler.js:324)
    at encodeOp (opcode-compiler.js:2588)
    at pushOp (opcode-compiler.js:2507)
    at opcode-compiler.js:1976
    at Compilers.compile (opcode-compiler.js:519)
    at compileStatements (opcode-compiler.js:2511)
    at maybeCompile (opcode-compiler.js:2490)
    at CompilableTemplateImpl.compile (opcode-compiler.js:2470)
    at VM.compile (runtime.js:6022)

Comment: Run `ember install @ember/render-modifiers`

Comment: Still got the same error ...  
I added this line 
<input5 {{did-insert this.searchuser}} {{on "keyup" (fn this.searchuser "search" search )}} > {{input type="text" value=search placeholder="Enter Text to Search" }}</input5>

Comment: Then you did smt wrong. The error clearly says that the modifier is not found and you add it to the project by installing it. Have you re-run ember server after installation?

Comment: It starts Working after i restart the ember and tomcat server.
But it is sending the data to servlet as   {"type":"search","searchtext":{}}
But I need to send the data as  {"type":"search","searchtext":""}
Because of sending different data it makes error in servlet side.

Comment: Ok, I guess you'll be able to adjust the modifier call yourself to fix the issue. Now when your original problem is solved would you mind to mark the answer as accepted?